# Unable to deploy Apache Pulsar on AKS. 'selectedNode annotation value "" not set'

Tags: kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, apache-pulsar

This is my first attempt to deploy Pulsar on AKS v1.15.11.

I'm getting a not very verbose error messages from 2 pods that are "unscheduled" :

[image]

Firtst pod unscheduled "pulsar-zookeeper-0"

> [Pod] [pulsar-zookeeper-0] FailedScheduling: selectedNode annotation value "" not set to scheduled node "aks-agentpool-20916223-vmss000001"

Second Pod unscheduled "pulsar-bookkeeper-0"

> [Pod] [pulsar-bookkeeper-0] FailedScheduling: selectedNode annotation value "" not set to scheduled node "aks-pulsar-20916223-vmss000001"

Here's a detailed procedure of what I did.
I've used official helm-charts for deployments

```
helm repo add kafkaesque https://helm.kafkaesque.io
helm repo update
```

Based on the documentation, I understood that I need to feed theese values in my storage_values.yaml file.

```
default_storage:
  provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-disk
  fsType: ext4
  type: managed-premium
  extraParams:
    storageaccounttype: Premium_LRS
    kind: Managed
    cachingmode: ReadOnly
```

Also created the namespace

```
{
  "kind": "Namespace",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
     "name": "pulsar",
     "labels": {
       "name": "pulsar"
     }
  }
}
```

Using this command

```
kubectl create -f namespace-pulsar.json
```

Then then I launched the deployment using the previous values

```
helm install pulsar kafkaesque/pulsar --namespace pulsar --values storage_values.yaml
```

Comment: I am guessing it can't create the premium disks (check `kubectl get pvc`). Try changing to the existing default storage class by setting `default_storage.existingStorageClassName: default`

Comment: I can see 3 pvc "pending" using `kubectl get pvc --namespace pulsar`. I'm going throught the documentation to find how to set the default storage class like you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AKS already comes with Storage Classes

you shouldn't need to tell your Chart to create a Storage Class using

```
default_storage:
  provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-disk
  fsType: ext4
  type: managed-premium
  extraParams:
    storageaccounttype: Premium_LRS
    kind: Managed
    cachingmode: ReadOnly
```

Instead update the `StorageClassName` variable to have your pods create their PVC using an existing Storage Class from AKS

run  `kubectl get sc` to get a list of all deployed storage classes

For your particular Chart,

Create a new file called storage_values.yaml for the storage class settings. To use an existing storage class (including the default one) set this value:

```
default_storage:
  existingStorageClassName: default or <name of storage class>
```

ref: https://helm.kafkaesque.io

Comment: What would be the best way to update the `StorageClassName` ?

Comment: https://helm.kafkaesque.io
Create a new file called storage_values.yaml for the storage class settings. To use an existing storage class (including the default one) set this value:

default_storage:
  existingStorageClassName: default or <name of storage class>

Comment: I guess I read the docs too fast and went straight to the cloud specific config instead of the default so thanks for pointing that out. I'll experiment a bit with the configuration to better understand why it failed...